Steampipe errors with relation "net_http_request" does not exist
I'm trying to run psql with against a local Steampipe Postgres service.
However, I get the following error from postgres/steampipe:
ERROR:  relation "net_http_request" does not exist
LINE 7:         net_http_request,
                ^

Here's a snippet of my query:
select
    r->>'full_name' as repository_full_name,
    r->>'default_branch' as default_branch
from
    net_http_request,
    jsonb_array_elements(response_body::jsonb) as r
where
    url = 'https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_GITHUB_ORG/repos?per_page=100&sort=full_name'

Where do I get the net_http_request relation from?

The relation net_http_request is part of the Steampipe turbo/net plugin, which one needs to install first.
To install the plugin, run:
steampipe plugin install net

After installing the plugin, ensure that it's loaded correctly by checking your Steampipe configuration or using:
steampipe plugin list

